# "Page Not Found" error when a google search form is submitted

Tags: 7, search

I am using Google Site Search on a web site, and the search form submits to a page containing the appropriate code. I can access this page directly just fine, but whenever I test out the search form, I get a "page not found" error.

I believe this is because both Drupal and Google search use the parameter 'q', has anyone run into this problem and found a workaround?

Comment: What is the path that you can access directly and what is the path that gives you 'page not found'?

Comment: example.com/search is the page with the google search code. page not found is the same path, example.com/search, but with the google search parameters.

Comment: I think there is an alternative parameter Google can use, and that would make it compatible with Drupal, but I don't recall which one is it, at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using *q*, you can use [as_q](http://www.google.com/cse/docs/resultsxml.html#as_qsp). The description given from the page I linked is the following:

> The as_q parameter provides search terms to check for in a document. This parameter is also commonly used to allow users to specify additional terms to search for within a set of search results.